# For loop decreasing order value

Tags: php

**Problem**
I have made the for loop decreasing but the value **$k** is not coming in opposite manner. Below is the code which am running to get it working any help will be great.

Basically am dealing with iFrame and I want to fetch the Parent URL data, for that i am using **$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']**. I am getting the parent URL perfectly but when am breaking the string I want it to be in opposite manner. Please look at the actual and desired result below.

**URL:** http://www.example.net/home?game_id=MyTeam11game_type=activity&auth=success

**Code**

```
$mainurl = array();
$mainurl = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
$mainurl = array_slice($mainurl, 3, true);
$mainurl = $mainurl['query'];
$mainurlArr = explode('&', $mainurl);
for($k=count($mainurlArr)-1; $k>=0; $k--){
    echo $mainurlArr[$k].' ,pos=> '.$k."<br />";
}
```

**Actual Output**

```
auth=success ,Actual pos=> 2
game_type=activity ,Actual pos=> 1
game_id=Pranavs%20running12 ,Actual pos=> 0
```

**Desired Output**

```
auth=success ,Actual pos=> 0
game_type=activity ,Actual pos=> 1
game_id=Pranavs%20running12 ,Actual pos=> 2
```

Comment: You could try placing them in an array and then array reverse: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php

Answer (score 2):

```
for($k=count($mainurlArr)-1, $i=0; $k>=0; $k--,$i++){
    echo $mainurlArr[$k].' ,pos=> '.$i."<br />";
}
```

Comment: mate I'm afraid but that's not really much helpful what I want is not only change of **$i** but also I want $i to be same as $k. Basically am trying to **Get** values from URL from in LIFO (Last in first out) format. If you can help me in that will be great.

Comment: @colourtheweb did you actually try this solution? because it does just that: you get LIFO results, but you get increasing numbers

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$start = count($mainurlArr)-1;

for($k=$start; $k>=0; $k--){
    echo $mainurlArr[$k].' ,pos=> '.($start - $k)."<br />";
}
```

(You might need to swap to `$k - $start`, as it's making my head hurt trying to work it out)

It subtracts the current index from the total, and displays that. I'm initialising it outside the loop to save a couple of function calls, and to keep the code a little tidier.

Comment: mate I'm afraid but that's not really much helpful what I want is not only change of **$i** but also I want $i to be same as $k. Basically am trying to **Get** values from URL from in LIFO (Last in first out) format. If you can help me in that will be great.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve the problem, here's the solution I was looking for. Thanks for the help.

```
$mainurl = array();
$mainurl = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
$mainurl = array_slice($mainurl, 3, true);
$mainurl = $mainurl['query'];
$mainurlArr = explode('&', $mainurl);

$m = count($mainurlArr)-1;
for($k=count($mainurlArr)-1; $k>=0; $k--){
    if($k == $m){
        $auth = substr($mainurlArr[$m],5);
        $_REQUEST['auth'] = $auth;
    }elseif($k == $m-1){
        $game_type = substr($mainurlArr[$m-1],10);
        $_REQUEST['game_type'] = $game_type;
    }elseif($k == $m-2){
        $game_id = substr($mainurlArr[$m-2],8);
        $_REQUEST['game_id'] = $game_id;
    }
}
```